# Necessity of [IO t0] in main::do

Tags: haskell

Let' consider:

```
main :: IO ()
main = 
    do
        args <- getArgs
        p <- args !! 0
```

ghc says:

```
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `IO t0'
    Expected type: [IO t0]
      Actual type: [String]
```

I cannot understand why `[IO t0]` is necessary here and how to repair ir.

Comment: You promised to return `IO ()` from `main`; the simplest solution is to add a `return ()` at the end of your `do`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that, in do-syntax, the expression to the right of the arrow must have a "lifted" or a "monadic" type. This is true in the case of `getArgs :: IO [String]`, which is why that line type-checks.

But in the next line `args !! 0` is constrained to have type `IO t0`, where `t0` is a type the typechecker introduces in the process of typechecking.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
          -- :: IO [String]
  p <- args !! 0
       -- :: IO t0, for some t0
  ...
```

Since the type checker is constrained by `args !! 0 :: IO t0`, it infers that `args` must have type `[IO t0]` (this follows from `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`). But this conflicts with `args :: [String]`, which causes that pretty-unhelpful error message you got.

What you actually want in this scenario is to perform a computation with `!!`, which is pure and doesn't return a value in `IO` at all. You can either "lift" the computation into `IO` with `pure` or `return`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
          -- :: IO [String]
  p <- pure (args !! 0)
       -- :: IO [String]
  ...
```

or you can use a notation specifically reserved for this situation, a `let`-binding:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
          -- :: IO [String]
  let p = args !! 0
          -- :: String
  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

`args` is a `[String]` so `args !! 0` is a `String`. Since the monad in `main` is `IO`, `p` needs to have type `IO a` for some `a` but it is a `String`. It looks like you want to use `let` instead:

```
main = 
    do
        args <- getArgs
        let p = args !! 0
        ...
```